# You cannot add or change a record because a related record is required in table 'tblCustomer'

Tags: database, ms-access, entity-relationship

I'm new to access and I don't know why this pop up `You cannot add or change a record because a related record is required in table 'tblCustomer'` keeps appearing every time I try to edit the order table.

I tried searching up the issue on this site but I still don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jNFYy.png

Comment: improved formatting

Answer (score 0):

It means that you are trying to add a record to the table tblOrder with the value in Customer_id, which is missing in the table tblCustomers. You need to add a new customer first, then refer to it in orders.